# Adjusting world raster to magnify Transatlantic region?

Tags: qgis, migration

My current project involves using a world sized raster to show Transatlantic migration. Because of the size of the Atlantic ocean in the raster, the lines indicating migration overlap and confuse the information that I'm trying to communicate.

Is there a good way to shorten the width of the ocean on the raster to give each line more clarity?

Alternatively, is there a source where I can find a good Transatlantic specific raster?

[image]

Comment: How are you presenting this information? In the print composer you could use two separate maps, one zoomed in on North America and the other zoomed in on Europe.

Comment: You could try different projected coordinate reference systems, although I'm not aware of any that compress the Atlantic ocean. Building a custom CRS might be a possible solution, but one that's outside my skill set.

Answer (score 1):

In Print Composer, you can use three separate maps to show your data.

Map 1:  Large map showing entire extent of data - the North Atlantic as well as eastern Canada and western Europe.

Under item properties, add an overview to this map and select map 2 for the map frame. Add another overview for map 3.

[image]

Maps 2 and 3: Closeup views of Europe and North America.

Use the Move Item Content button to move each of the map views around until the arrows line up correctly.

Note: Use a categorized style on the arrows, with a unique color for each arrow. This will help you line them up correctly.

[image]